# Best statistical test to compare proportions of count data

Tags: statistical-significance, biostatistics

I have taken photos of 30 animals moving around an arena. The arena has 4 different configurations, and I have 500 photos for each animal in each type of arena (taken throughout the day). I have gone through all the photos and classified how many photos are on the left, the right or the middle of the arena. I want to test whether the arena's configuration affects the amount of time (or in my case n of photos) the animal spent on each side (or middle). Possibly accounting for the ID of the animal (if there is personality bias etc). What would be the best test for this? Basically my data looks like this:

Animal ID (1,2...30), Arena_config (1,2,3 or 4), N photos left(N between 0 and 500), N photos mid(N between 0 and 500), N photos right(N between 0 and 500).

The total n of photos per arena_config totals to 500, and I have four arena_config per animal.

Thank you!

Comment: When you say "photos are on the left, the right or the middle of the arena", do you mean taken from a left/right/middle angle? Or do you mean the animal is on the left/right/middle of the arena?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand (please correct me if I'm wrong), your data characterizes $P(location,arena,animal)$ and your question is whether $P(location|arena)=P(location)$, in other words is $location$ independent from $arena$ or not. In that case, you can use a test of independence and check the associated p-value. See an example [here](http://www.stat.wmich.edu/s216/book/node112.html).

Note that the arena makes calculations a bit more tedious compared to the example in the link I've shared. But the principles still hold.

Comment: Another similar example is given on Wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chi-squared_test#Example_chi-squared_test_for_categorical_data

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you could use a binomial test to test whether the proportion of each corner differs depending on the orientation on the arena. If you wanted to test whether the animal does not go to a corner randomly, you would test H_0: p = 1/4. If you want to test between 2 configurations, for corner 1 say, you would use H_0: p = (the proportion observed in configuration either 1 or 2 in corner 1) and use the data you observe from the remaining configuration to compute the p-value.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_test